# At thermal equilibrium, do the energies of the 2 systems equalize?

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose we have 2 systems with energies $E_1$ and $E_2$ respectively that are in contact with each other until thermalization occurs. The temperatures of the 2 systems equalize but do the energies $E_1$ and $E_2$ equalize as well?

My guess is not because if you have a bigger system and a smaller system, the bigger system will probably still have more energy than the smaller one when the temperatures equalize.

Comment: You are correct. There is no need for $E_1 = E_2$ at equilibrium

Comment: Have you considered that the answer can be quite different when you ask about intrinsic properties rather than extrinsic properties as well as when you ask about ideal gases or non-ideal materials?

Comment: Note that there is a difference between total energy and energy per particle

Comment: @Aaron Stevens Would energy per particle become equal? Is that a proxy for temperature?

Comment: @Thomas For certain systems (like the ideal gas) it is true that you can think of temperature as a measure of the energy per particle, and in these systems equilibrium (equal temperature) means equal energy per particle. However, in general what you can say is that if $T_1=T_2$ then $$\left(\frac{\partial S_1}{\partial U_1}\right)_{V_1,N_1}=\left(\frac{\partial S_2}{\partial U_2}\right)_{V_2,N_2}$$